# spriteKit object not displayed when drawing background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am using xCode 6 beta 4 to build a game. In iOS 8 , everything works fine but in iOS 7.0 simulator, the player object isn't displayed.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, I changed background.zPosition to -100 and now I can see the player object. It is still weird why this wasn't required at iOS 8.0 .

My Code:

```
class PlayScene : SKScene{


    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background1")
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    var ForceX = CGVectorMake(250, 0)
    let Gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -15)
    var bgVelocity = CGFloat(0)
    var maxBgY = CGFloat(0)
    var origRunningBGPosition = CGFloat(0)
    var isJumping=false
    var startedJump = false


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView!) {

        self.player.position=CGPointMake(150, 150)
        self.player.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.player.size)
        self.player.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=false
        self.player.physicsBody.mass=CGFloat(1)



        self.background.size=CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, self.frame.height*3)
        self.background.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0)
        self.background.position=CGPointMake(0, 0)
        bgVelocity+=2.5
        self.maxBgY=self.background.size.height-self.frame.height
        maxBgY*=CGFloat(-1)
        self.origRunningBGPosition=CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)

         self.addChild(self.background)
         self.addChild(self.player)


    }
```

What I found out is that when I don't use background , I can see the player, and I can't understand why it is happening and why in iOS 7.0 only?

Comment: Did you try with `zPosition`?

Comment: @Desdenova what do you mean? Please explain

Comment: Read SKNode class reference for z position.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I changed background.zPosition to -100 and now I can see the player object. It still weird why this wasn't required at iOS 8.0 .

Comment: Seems like iOS 8 handles the z position by child order then. Nevertheless always try to set the z to be certain.

Comment: From Apple's documentation, "The default value [of SKView's ignoresSiblingOrder property] is NO, which means that when multiple nodes share the same z position, those nodes are sorted and rendered in a deterministic order. Parents are rendered before their children, and siblings are rendered from eldest to youngest."

Answer (score 0):

When you define your skView in your viewDidLoad in your viewController that holds the skScenes put this and everything will act as it use to

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO;
```